# How to read in a file into a structure in C when the file contains special characters to control the process

Tags: c, arrays, file, formatting, structure

I've been trying for hours to read in this file into a structure which I want to use in my C programming project. I can't get it to work properly with the structure.

Here's the file I want to read in:

```
# category
- word to guess
*information to help you to guess the word

- another word to guess
* information to help you to guess the word

# another category
- word to guess
*information to help you to guess the word

- another word to guess
* information to help you to guess the word
```

**Here's my code** (which doesn't seem to work):

```
char retazec[50]; // here goes the read in string from the file
char kategoria[50]; // here the category name is stored

i = 0; // index for the array of structures
j = 1;
while (!feof(otazky)) {
    fgets(retazec, 50, otazky);
    if (strchr(retazec, '#') != NULL) {
        printf("%s", retazec);
        printf("%d\n", i);
        slova[i].kategoria = retazec;
        strcpy(kategoria, retazec);
    }
    if (strchr(retazec, '-') != NULL) {
        printf("%s", retazec);
        printf("%d\n", i-j);
        slova[i-j].slovo = retazec;
        j++;
    }
    if (strchr(retazec, '*') != NULL) {
        printf("%s", retazec);
        printf("%d\n", i-j);
        slova[i-j].napoveda = retazec;
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}

putchar('\n');
putchar('\n');
printf("%s", slova[0].kategoria);
printf("%s", slova[0].slovo);
printf("%s", slova[0].napoveda);
```

**How I hoped it would work**:

I've got the `i` variable to store the index for the array of structures. The `j` variable is for correcting the array index.

1. The first string is read (# category)
2. If it does contain a `'\#'`, remember what category it is and put it into `slova[i].kategoria` (`i` is 0)
3. It checks for the other two and increments `i`
4. The second string is read (`-` word to guess)
5. The first `if` is false, in the second one, if the string contains a `'-'`, put it into `slova[i-j].slovo` (`i` is 1, `j` is 1 so `i - j = 0`) and than it increments `j` because in the next step, when the program is going to read the information to help the user guess, `i` is going to be 2, `j` as well and `i - j` gives us 0 again. And as I thought, these 3 strings should be in the `slova[0]` structure. But it does not work and I can't find out why.

If anybody knows the answer, please help me.

Comment: What kind of structure are you after? I'd initially thought that a struct that contained 2 strings would be sufficient - catagoryName and categoryHintText. I then realized that there are 2 entries starting with each of `-` and `*` between a single pair of `# category` tags. This made me wonder, do you need a struct that (a) contains an element that holds it's category name _and_ (b) contains a list of [wordToGuess, infoToHelpGuessTheWord]? If so, it would need 2 structs. One struct for category info, and another for item info (a linked list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gawd almighty. It's projects like this that remind me of some of the benefits of C++, namely vectors and lists. Either would simplify the task considerably.

It seems to me that you'd need to keep (a) a linked list of the categories read (b) a linked list in each of the categories that holds the word/hint pairs for that cat.

I've only bothered to make a linked list of words/hints in each category. I simply overwrite the previous category any time a new one is encountered. I also burn memory like it's rocket-fuel that I stole. :-D

When dealing with the categories, you may wish follow the pattern I've used for the items linked list, or you may choose to use an array along with realloc.

Anyway, hope its helpful and of use to you. :-)

**main.c**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct sItem
{
    char    *wordToGuess;
    char    *wordGuessHint;
    sItem   *next;
};

struct sCat
{
    char    *categoryName;
    sItem   *itemList;
};

sItem *newItem(char *word, char *hint)
{
    sItem *tmp;
    tmp = (sItem*)malloc(sizeof(sItem));
    tmp->wordToGuess = word;
    tmp->wordGuessHint = hint;
    return tmp;
}

sItem *getTail(sItem *head)
{
    sItem *tmp;
    tmp = head;
    while (tmp->next != NULL)
        tmp = tmp->next;
    return tmp;
}

void addListItem(sItem **listHead, char *word, char *wordHint)
{
    sItem *tmp1, *theNewNode = newItem(word, wordHint);

    // list is empty
    if ((*listHead) == NULL)
        (*listHead) = theNewNode;

    // find end of list and add entry there
    else
    {
        tmp1 = getTail(*listHead);
        tmp1->next = theNewNode;
    }
}

// display a list of sItems (each category has it's own list)
void printList(sItem *listHead)
{
    sItem *tmp = listHead;
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        printf("Word: %s\n", tmp->wordToGuess);
        printf("Hint: %s\n", tmp->wordGuessHint);
        printf("\n");
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}

void printCategory(sCat &cat)
{
    printf("Category: %s\n", cat.categoryName);
    printList(cat.itemList);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argCount, char *argValues[])
{
    char lineBuffer[256];
    sCat curCategory;
    char *curStr=NULL, *curWord=NULL, *curHint=NULL;
    bool isFirst = true;
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    curCategory.itemList = NULL;
    while (fgets(lineBuffer, 255, fp) != NULL)
    {
        // 1. trim trailing new-line character
        lineBuffer[ strlen(lineBuffer) - 1] = 0;
        // 2. set pointer to point to first char of 'data' in the line
        curStr = lineBuffer + 2;
        switch (lineBuffer[0])
        {
            case '#':                       // category
                if (isFirst != true)
                {
                    printCategory(curCategory);
                }
                curCategory.categoryName = strdup(curStr);
                curCategory.itemList = NULL;
//                printf("# [%s]\n", curStr);
                isFirst = false;
                break;
            case '-':                       // word
                curWord = strdup(curStr);
//                printf("- [%s]\n", curStr);
                break;
            case '*':                       // hint
                curHint = strdup(curStr);
                addListItem(&curCategory.itemList, curWord, curHint);
 //               printf("* [%s]\n", curStr);
                break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printCategory(curCategory);
}
```

**data.txt**

```
# Animals
- Zebra
* Black + white stripes

- Girraffe
* Tall orange

# Cars
- Mustang
* A real 'animal' of a car

- Lamborghini Diablo
* A devillishly good ride.
```

**Output:**

```
Category: Animals
Word: Zebra
Hint: Black + white stripes

Word: Girraffe
Hint: Tall orange


Category: Cars
Word: Mustang
Hint: A real 'animal' of a car

Word: Lamborghini Diablo
Hint: A devillishly good ride.



Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.080 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are looping through the file, you are reading data into the `retazec` buffer, then you test to see if it is a category, word or hint. When it's a category, you are copying the category name in

`strcpy(kategoria, retazec)`

However, when it is a word or a hint, you're just setting a pointer to the read buffer

`slova[i-j].napoveda = retazec;`

but the very next read destroys that value (overwrites it).

You should be copying the value, not assigning a pointer there. You cannot assign strings, you have to copy them.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you both K Scott Piel and enhzflep**
Since I can't use linked lists, because this is a school project and they haven't taught us how to use them, I have come up with this (and suprisingly it works as I want it to):

```
char retazec[50];
char kategoria[50];

i = 0;
j = 0;
printf("%d\n", pocet_slov);
while (fgets(retazec, 50, otazky) != NULL) {
    switch(retazec[0]) {
    case '#':
        strcpy(kategoria, retazec);
        strcpy(slova[i-j].kategoria, retazec);
        j++;
        break;
    case '-':
        strcpy(slova[i-j].kategoria, kategoria);
        strcpy(slova[i-j].slovo, retazec);
        j++;
        break;
    case '*':
        strcpy(slova[i-j].napoveda, retazec);
        j++;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}

fclose(otazky);

for (i = 0; i < pocet_slov; i++) {
    putchar('\n');
    putchar('\n');
    printf("%s", slova[i].kategoria);
    printf("%s", slova[i].slovo);
    printf("%s", slova[i].napoveda);
}
```

**Output:**
# category
- word
* help to guess the word
# category
- word
* help to guess the word

Then, if it finds another category it goes like:
# another category
- word
* help
# another category
- word
* help